# Compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} \, (1-2^n(1-\Phi(\frac{x}{n}))^n)$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

At one point, in an exercise, I find myself computing the following limit

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \, (1-2^n(1-\Phi(\frac{x}{n}))^n)$  $ \ \ \ \ x > 0$

where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

I'm stuck, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use a Taylor expansion of $\Phi$ about $0$. (First order suffices.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so hard at least with direct point-wise limit.
Note that $\Phi(u) \approx \Phi(0) + \Phi'(0)u = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}u$ with $O(u^2)$ error. This will be sufficient for a limit calculation.

Therefore, for every *fixed* $x$ we will have

$\Phi(x/n) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$,

$1 - 2^n(1-\Phi(\frac{x}{n}))^n = 1 - \left[1 - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2}) \right]^n \rightarrow 1-\exp{\left( - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right)}$

as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for every fixed $x$